# edit in place and change value to database also?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am using [editable](http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html) plugin to edit-in-place. I am able to do it on the web page but I want to change this value to the database also.

Here is the php/html code :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
    {


                echo "<tr class='highlighter'><td class='editable-1'>".$row['subcategory_name']."</td>";

             echo  "</tr>";

    }
```

and the jquery code is as follows :

```
$(document).ready(function() 
    { 
        $('.editable-1').editable({onEdit:begin});
        function begin(){
            this.append('Click somewhere else to submit');

        }
    } 
);
```

I am trying to use **ajax** but not getting the value when I am updating in textbox.

Here is what I am trying to do

```
$.ajax({
url:'change_subcat.php',
data:'NOT AVAILABLE'
});
```

Please tell me how to made changes also in database.

Comment: You have to use ajax to perform this operation. have a look at $.ajax

Comment: @KD I have updated my question Please check it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to submit the data via ajax to the server, where you need a script to process the data and save it to your database.

It looks like in this plugin, you can attach a listener to the `onEdit` event that will submit your data, maybe something like this:

```
$('.editable-1').editable({onEdit: submitData});
function submitData (content) {
    $.post('/save_to_db.php', { data: content.current });
 }
```

From the documentation for this plugin, it appears that the callback is called with an object for an argument (`content`, in this case) that has `previous` and `current` properties. You should be able to get the new value of the editable field with `content.current`.

Comment: Great! I'm glad that was what you needed!

Comment: There is one more thing to consider here this is working fine but it is performing ajax when I am clicking on first time. That means value is updating in database but the value is the same which was previous one while I want to save new value and at this time ajax is not working. Ajax should work when I click on out side of that <td> I hope you are getting me

Comment: I think I see what you are saying - you want to submit the data when the user clicks, tabs, etc. away from the textarea inserted by the plugin. If this is the case, you should attach your handler to `onSubmit` instead of `onEdit`.

Comment: Yes I want to do this but now the thing is when I am doing this I am able to get the last value but I need already seen value too so that I can update that.

Comment: then you can use `content.previous`

Comment: Andrew You are awesome.Hey Andrew Please tell me from where you are reading these values.

Comment: I found it somewhat buried in the plugin docs: http://www.arashkarimzadeh.com/jquery/7-editable-jquery-plugin.html Glad to help.

Comment: Thanks for all the above help. Now I have one more thing.I am using **confirm** popup before editing the value. When user clicks on yes button then it should update otherwise it should not update. yes operation is working superb but how to stop to change value if I click on No button. Since I am updating these values in <td> tag of table and <td> do not have any id.